# Displaying a Flattened Phoenix Expression using Boost Fusion

Tags: c++, boost, boost-fusion, boost-phoenix, boost-proto

Following the [Expressions as Fusion Sequences](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/proto/users_guide.html#boost_proto.users_guide.intermediate_form.expressions_as_fusion_sequences) section of the Proto User Guide, I get to the point where I iterate over a flattened proto expression: `_1 + 2 + 3 + 4`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>

namespace proto   = boost::proto;
namespace fusion  = boost::fusion;
namespace phoenix = boost::phoenix;

struct display
{
  template<typename T>
  void operator()(T const &t) const
  {
    std::cout << t << std::endl;
  }
};

boost::proto::terminal<int>::type const _1 = {1};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  fusion::for_each(
    fusion::transform(
      proto::flatten(_1 + 2 + 3 + 4)
    , proto::functional::value()
    )
  , display()
  );
  return 0;
}
```

The `_1` placeholder is defined as shown above using `proto::terminal`. I'd also like to use
Boost Phoenix; however, if I instead use the version of `_1` defined in `boost::phoenix::arg_names` in the call to `fusion::for_each`, I get an **error: cannot bind ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream}’ lvalue to ‘std::basic_ostream&&’**. Can I use Phoenix placeholders like this with a Fusion transform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no ostream inserter for `phoenix::arg_names::_1`. We can easily add one, though. This compiles for me with clang++ (trunk):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>

namespace proto   = boost::proto;
namespace fusion  = boost::fusion;
namespace phoenix = boost::phoenix;

struct display
{
  template<typename T>
  void operator()(T const &t) const
  {
    std::cout << t << std::endl;
  }
};

namespace boost { namespace phoenix
{
  template<int N>
  std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& sout, argument<N> const& arg)
  {
    return sout << "_" << N;
  }
}}

int main()
{
  fusion::for_each(
    fusion::transform(
      proto::flatten(phoenix::arg_names::_1 + 2 + 3 + 4)
    , proto::functional::value()
    )
  , display()
  );
}
```

Comment: Do you by any chance know why I get an error with `proto::display_expr(fusion::at_c<0>(proto::flatten(_1+2+3+4)));`?

Comment: @user2023370 `fusion::at_c` requires a [`Random Access Sequence`](http://www.boost.org/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/sequence/concepts/random_access_sequence.html) and the result of `proto::flatten` is just a [`Forward Sequence`](http://www.boost.org/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/sequence/concepts/forward_sequence.html). You can use `proto::display_expr(fusion::at_c<0>(fusion::as_vector(proto::flatten(_1+2+3+4))));`.